# Displaying only the detected region and blacking out all other regions in an image in JAVA

Tags: java, javacv, skin, imagej

I am trying to incorporate skin detection as well as viola jones object detection in my application for accurate detection of hand. I am using JAVACV

this is what i am trying to do

```
    SkinImage = detect.skin(InputImage);
```

This will return an image with skin regions marked as white and all other regions as black, binary image

After this i would like to **AND the "SkinImage" and "InputImage" from which i should get an image with only skin regions visible in skin colour and all other regions blacked out** like applying a binary mask to an image. So the question is how do i AND these two images??

I know it can be done in C++ with SkinImage &=InputImage;

How can i do it in JAVA using JAVACV or other libraries like ImageJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageJ, you can do the following to apply a mask to an RGB image:

```
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.plugin.ImageCalculator;

[...]

ImageCalculator ic = new ImageCalculator();
ImagePlus imp3 = ic.run("AND create", imp1, imp2);
```

with `imp1` and `imp2` being instances of the [`ImagePlus` class](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html?ij/ImagePlus.html), `imp1` being the original image (e.g. RGB) and `imp2` being the binary mask image.

To get this code, I was running *Process > [Image Calculator](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-29.html#toc-Subsection-29.13)...* while running the [macro recorder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-14.html#toc-Section-14) (*Plugins > Macros > Record...*) in *Java* mode.